# CSS hover/active touch feedback not working on mobile until react-select is shown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am struggling to debug the issue here. Until a react-select is shown on the UI the feedback on mobile touch elements do not provide feedback on touch.

This can be seen here by completing the journey on mobile until step 4:
https://odd-panda-design.badgerbookings.com/booking

When you first interact with the elements there is no feedback however when you get to the 4th screen in the journey and click "signup" (showing the react select) the hover elements suddenly provide feedback if you navigate back to them. This issue is only on mobile and not web. I have tested on iPhone 6 using Chrome.

Below is the react-select element that triggers the touch feedback interactions.

[image]

I have tried adding `onTouchStart` and changing the hover elements to include `:active` or `:focus`

I am not sure if this is a react or javascript issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by feedback, exactly. Do you mean the hover onmouseover? If so, it actually works on my phone. Android Chrome.

Comment: Hi there @EssamAl-Mansouri. I was refering to the touch element. I.e. when a user clicks a actionable element the hover CSS should appear. That is good it works on Android. I can replicate the issue on web using the "mobile" layout option in inspect element.

Answer (score 3):

I had dealt with this before.

Try adding `onclick=""` to any element that requires ios to recognize as hover element.

As a side note, try abstracting the problem. Remove react select and see if it works, if not, continue abstracting and see when the problem disappears.

Comment: hi @shmotam .. The actual elements already have a onClick on them to handle the logic